# Angular2 FormGroup in FormArray validation

Tags: angular, validation, angular2-forms

I have the following model:

```
export interface Content {
  lang: string;
  title: string;
}
```

I need to validate a `contents FormArray` of this `parent FormGroup`:

```
this.formBuilder.group({
  defaultLang: ['', Validators.required],
  contents: this.formBuilder.array([], Validators.minLength(1))
});
```

For each `Content` in my `contents FormArray`, I validate the model with the following `content FormGroup`:

```
this.formBuilder.group({
  lang: ['', Validators.required],
  title: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

For now, I add the following `content FormGroup` to my `contents FormArray` to validate each `Content`:

```
(<FormArray>parentFormGroup.controls['contents'])
    .push(this.contentFormGroup);
```

But with this approach I can't validate these rules:

- If one of the `Content` fields are filled up then content validation occurs (which means adding the `content FormGroup` to the `contents FormArray`)
- If none of the content fields are filled up then no content validation occurs (which means removing the `content FormGroup` of the `contents FormArray` if present)
- If `lang` of a `Content` is the `defaultLang` of the `parent FormGroup`, then the content is required.

**Questions**

Is there a work around of adding/removing the `content FormGroup` of the `contents FormArray` just with validators?

Is there a way to do it with Angular native validators only?

Do I need to create a custom validator? If yes, do you have great example to do so with `FormArray`?

Comment: Could you create a plunker? I have a bit of trouble piecing this code together? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add validator to the group like below

```
 this.group = this.formBuilder.group({
        lang: ['', Validators.required],
        title: ['', Validators.required]
    });

    this.group.setValidators([          
        this.titleRequiredValidator(),
    ]);



    private titleRequiredValidator(): ValidatorFn {
        return (group: FormGroup): { [key: string]: any } => {
        const langControl = group.controls.lang;
        const titleControl = group.controls.title;

        if (langControl.value !== '' && titleControl.value == '')) {
            const error = { required: true };
            titleControl.setErrors(error);
            return error;
        }            
        else {
            titleControl.setErrors(null);
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```